# Permissions issues with running Ola Hallengren's MaintenanceSolution.sql script on Amazon RDS Sql Server 2008

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I'd like to use Ola Hallengren's MaintenanceSolution.sql script to create index and stats maintenance jobs on an Amazon RDS SQL Server 2008 R2 DB.

- **Documentation**: http://ola.hallengren.com
- **SQL Script**: http://ola.hallengren.com/scripts/MaintenanceSolution.sql

The problem is that currently, the `sysadmin` role is not available on RDS instances, and parts of this script require that role to execute.

I was able to get around most of this by executing the script on a custom DB rather than `master`, and by suppressing the `IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin')` check on line 41.

However, I am running into issues later on with the `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs` calls at the bottom of the script, and I cannot find a way to grant read permissions on `msdb.dbo.sysjobs` via an RDS SQL Server DB.

Has anyone successfully run this script, *including* the jobs creation portion on an Amazon RDS SQL Server 2008 R2 DB?